# How to specify font size less than 10pt in latex

Tags: latex

I'm trying to make a document that has a very small font throughout, I tried this:

```
\documentclass[0.5mm, a4paper]{article}
\documentclass[7pt, a4paper]{article}
```

But it doesn't seem that they allow me to go anything below 10pt.

This hack make it work, but not for the section headers:

```
\fontsize{4mm}{5mm}\selectfont
```

Does anyone know any better ways to do this?

Comment: Try asking this question on tex.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know stackexchange got tex site as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use one of the KOMA-Script classes (scrartcl in this case), it should work:

```
 \documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=5mm]{scrartcl}
   \addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}
```

You can also consult the [extensive manual](ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguide.pdf), KOMA offers more features than that.

Comment: Hmm the KOMA manual that you linked to seems to be written in dutch, but that's ok. I googled it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @the_great_monkey: Sorry, it's german, the english one is called scrguien.pdf. (But Markus' english curls my toenails.)

Answer (score -1):

Not specific, but I always use one of these:

```
\tiny
\small
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge
\Huge
```